# Unable to use variables inside promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, firebase-storage

I am trying to updload a picture to firebase storage, no problem with that.

However when I try to set the state with the image URL and some other things that I am getting from a form, my variables (section and price) are empty inside the promise. Below my code:

```
    handleForm = e =>{
    e.preventDefault();

    const {section, price, image} = e.target

    const file = image.files[0]
    const pictureName = userInformation.name.replace(/ /g, "_");
    if(file.size <= 1000000){
      const myRoute = '/img/userPictures/' + pictureName;
      const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(myRoute);
      const task = storageRef.put(file);
      task.on('state_changed', snapshot =>{
        console.log('Uploaded');
      }, error =>{
        console.log(error.message)
      }, () =>{
        task.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(downloadURL =>{
          this.setState({
            information: this.state.data.concat([{
              section: section.value, 
              price: price.value, 
              image:downloadURL}])
          })
        });
      })
      e.currentTarget.reset();
      this.notifySuccess('Information uploaded');
    }else{
      this.notifyError('Image should be less than 1 MB')
    }
    }
```

Where do I have the error? thanks!

Comment: can you please tell what kind of error you are getting here ?

Comment: When I try to set the state, section and price are empty, it only sets the image with the downloadURL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are using `e.currentTarget.reset()` outside the callback.
Try to put it inside on the success of your callback, it should work as expected
(As shown below)

```
handleForm = e => {
    e.preventDefault()

    const {section, price, image} = e.target

    const file = image.files[0]
    const pictureName = userInformation.name.replace(/ /g, '_')
    if (file.size <= 1000000) {
        const myRoute = '/img/userPictures/' + pictureName
        const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(myRoute)
        const task = storageRef.put(file)
        task.on(
            'state_changed',
            snapshot => {
                console.log('Uploaded')
            },
            error => {
                console.log(error.message)
            },
            () => {
                task.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(downloadURL => {
                    this.setState({
                        information: this.state.data.concat([
                            {
                                section: section.value,
                                price: price.value,
                                image: downloadURL
                            }
                        ])
                    })
                })
                e.currentTarget.reset()
                this.notifySuccess('Information uploaded')
            }
        )
    } else {
        this.notifyError('Image should be less than 1 MB')
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer, when I try that, it does not clear the form for some reason.

Comment: Never mind Sathak, I did not place it where you advised, it works now, thanks for you support!